# How to convert an Enum to ViewModel

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Web Api to build a ViewModel based on the Enum. This view model will be sending id and the name. Basically I want to use this viewModel to use dropdownList.

**Here is my code: works fine but I don't want to use ListItem in Web Api.**

```
// GET api/values
    public List<DropdownViewModel> Get()
    {
        List<DropdownViewModel> ddlList = new List<DropdownViewModel>();

        foreach (int r in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CountryEnum)))
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem(Enum.GetName(typeof(CountryEnum), r), r.ToString());
            ddlList.Add(new DropdownViewModel
            {
                id = item.Value,
                name = item.Text                    
            });
        }

        return ddlList;
    }
```

Can anyone re-factor this code without using ListItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linq *Select* method should work.

**Edit: That just goes to show that if it's not tested it doesn't work. This is tested. It should work.**

```
public List<DropdownViewModel> Get()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof (CountryEnum)).Cast<int>()
        .Select(id => new DropdownViewModel
        {
            id = id,
            name = Enum.GetName(typeof (CountryEnum), id)
        }).ToList();
}
```